# Using UnitOfWork with the Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Very new to FluentNHibernate, but I'm also excited about the area. I've recently started work on a new DAL using the aforementioned and have been reading up on the Repository pattern. I like the generic form this pattern takes and am looking to use this pattern in conjunction with the UnitOfWork pattern for session management.

I'm curious, is this the right direction to head? Should I be using UoW to create a pseudo-singleton NHibernate session? This question really dances around the topic of NHibernate session management. There is a [UoW implementation available](http://hibernatingrhinos.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/UnitOfWork/) that I've taken a look at, although I'm also unclear if I should be working to implement this library, or abstract my own.

EDIT:

Just for re-clarification of the question:

Is it common practice to use the UoW pattern with the Repository pattern in a FluentNHibernate environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for a good example check out [FubuMVC-Contrib's implementation](http://code.google.com/p/fubumvc-contrib/source/browse/trunk/samples/AltOxite/AltOxite.Core/Persistence/) of these.

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of "can I do X with Fluent NHibernate" questions - just to clarify Fluent NHibernate sits on top of NHibernate and spits out those horrible XML mappings for you... it doesn't affect what you can and can't do with NHibernate.

Comment: Thank you for the response DanB. Actually, the fact that I'm using Fluent doesn't affect the above question. I'm referring to the ability of using the Repository pattern for persistence in conjunction with the Unit Of Work pattern for session management and was confused on the idea of them coinciding. NHibernate was only noted as session management might be unique(ie, LINQ sessions are another story entirely).

Comment: Fair point - back on topic: I found the following useful for getting my head around the UoW pattern: http://www.codeinsanity.com/2008/09/unit-of-work-pattern.html
http://www.codeinsanity.com/2008/10/implementing-persistence-ignorant-unit.html

which borrows heavily from Ayende's work in Rhino Commons http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Commons.ashx